# Python grading program, need help w/ Ranging issue

Tags: python, range

Simple python program that takes the float value and returns the corresponding grade.
I am having trouble ranging the grades so that right grade will be given to the marks. What is my problem here...? (I rather not use the 'and' conditions)

```
def grade(mark):
    if mark >= 80:
        letter = 'A'
    elif 65 >= mark <= 79:
        letter = 'B'
    elif 50 >= mark <= 64:
        letter = 'C'
    else:
        letter = 'F'
    return letter
```

Comment: `elif 65 >= mark <= 79:` it's basically `if mark <= 65`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return early for values over a limit, so there is no need to test for that upper limit again:

```
def grade(mark):
    if mark >= 80:
        return 'A'
    if mark >= 65:
        return 'B'
    if mark >= 50:
        return 'C'
    return 'F'
```

Your chained comparisons had the lower bound the wrong way around; you were testing if `mark` was *smaller* than 65; invert the tests:

```
elif 65 <= mark <= 79:
    letter = 'B'
elif 50 <= mark <= 64:
    letter = 'C'
```

The most efficient approach is to use [`bisect.bisect()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) and two lists:

```
import bisect

def grade(mark):
    grades = ['F', 'C', 'B', 'A']
    marks = [50, 65, 80]
    return grades[bisect.bisect(marks, mark)]
```

`bisect.bisect()` returns the index into which a `mark` would be inserted; 0-49 would be inserted at index 0 (translating to `'F'`), 50-64 would be inserted at index 1 (`'C'`), etc.

Comment: TIL you can chain inequalities. Nice!

Answer (score 5):

`65 >= mark <= 79` is shorthand for:

```
65 >= mark and mark <= 79
```

All values less than 65 are also less than or equal to 79, but this won't find values actually in the range you're looking for.

You probably meant `65 <= mark <= 79`

(As pointed out in the comments, if `mark` is a float even correcting this error will leave your function discontinuous since there are valid values, like 79.5, that you don't account for.)

Comment: actually `65 >= mark and mark <= 79` will return True for all values lower or equal to 65. It's not incorrect it's just redundant.

Comment: @HerrActress: fixed. Clearly needed more coffee before writing that sentence. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused - you say you're using floats...what do you want to do with 79.5, for instance?

```
if mark >= 80:
    letter = 'A'
elif mark > = 70:
    letter = 'B'
```

etc....you only need to set the lower value, really.